# Spring Boot - can't read custom properties from application.yml

Tags: spring-boot

I added to my application.yml the following section:

```
app: 
  host: server.com
```

I injected the Environment to my class (RestController):

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

But reading the value returns null:

```
System.out.println( environment.getProperty( "app.host" ) );
```

What is the correct way to achieve that? Will it be the same for nested properties like 'app.config.serviceA.host' ?

Comment: Tried to implement @ConfigurationProperties as described here https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/ but no success, all POGOs are empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a class variable with the value annotation inside any annotated class @Component, @Repository, etc..

```
@Value("${app.host}")
private String host;
```

Comment: My fault, it is working, was working with wrong copy of application.yml.. So Value annotated field and injected Environment is working, but not the @ConfigurationProperties approach, any idea why?

Comment: Another my fault, had wrong mapping in my POJO, so @ConfigurationProperties is working as well.